# How could hosted payment field change parent div class?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Recently, I am working on the Hosted Payment Fields https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/your-checkout-our-iframes/. And when i input something wrong, The container div 's class is changed, how does this worked? I think there is no way to call the parent with different domain?

the code with bad input.(class : "braintree-hosted-fields-invalid")

```
    <div class="form-control braintree-hosted-fields-invalid" id="hosted-fields-number">
        <iframe src="https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.15.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#5c7db060-9271-4eac-b4a2-0f405d743293" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" type="number" name="braintree-hosted-field-number" id="braintree-hosted-field-number" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left;">
        </iframe>
    <div style="clear: both;">
```

Comment: oh dear!! They have validations in the frame itself not on the parent.

Comment: thx..may be my poor english....I know the validation is in the frame , but the div with id 'hosted-fields-number' is changed..i'll try to check the web messaging thing..

Comment: so is that div in your parent page or the frame?

Comment: in parent page.And although the js file is compressed, but i found it was posting some messages. So i think T.J.Crowder is right.

Answer (score 0):

They're presumably using [web messaging](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/), which is specifically designed to provide cross-origin communication. So their script running on the parent page listens for messages from their script running in the iframe and responds to those messages by updating the classes on the field.